# Sqoop Incremental import and update

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to import data from sql into a hive database. The goal is to update the changes in the oracle database to hive using sqoop import. The sqoop command is as follows:

```
sqoop import -D mapred.child.java.opts='\-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom' 
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=ON)(FAILOVER=ON)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=)(PORT=1545))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=)(PORT=1545)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))'
 --username abcde  
--password 1234rgtds  
--table Customer_Acc 
--columns Name,ID,Address,Date_booking ,Last_update_date
-m 1
 --target-dir /final/table 
 --hive-import 
--hive-table tesupd 
--map-column-hive Name,ID,Address,Date_booking
 --null-string '\\N' 
--null-non-string '\\N' 
--hive-delims-replacement ' ' 
--incremental lastmodified 
--check-column Last_update_date
--last-value "2009-12-31 12:14:28"
```

The final output should be the data greater than the last value, but in the above case it is appending the data instead of incrementally updating it.

I want the data to be updated rather than appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `--merge-key` option in your `sqoop-import` command. This will replace the older records with the latest records.

Alternately you can use `sqoop-merge` command as well but it should be done in two steps. First `sqoop-import` without `merge-key` and then `sqoop-merge`

Answer (score 1):

Try using --incremental append rather than --incremental last modified.

With --incremental append last-value of field mentioned is stored in sqoop metastore 'incremental.last.value' which keeps changing whenever the job is executed. Using --incremental append you do not have to update the last-value in your query but it is updated automatically.

By this your value will always be updated (in sqoop metastore) and there will not be any redundant data

Comment: Hi Sahiliv i would like to update the data using the DATE column. Please, Let me know if it works with date.

Answer (score 1):

Neither sqoop nor Hive can directly update the data in Hive using sqoop imports. Please follow the steps in the below link for row level updates.

http://hortonworks.com/blog/four-step-strategy-incremental-updates-hive/

Comment: Thanks for this link.It was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So your data is mutable and you'd like to modify in HDFS the records which have been changed in your DB.

For this, you need to use the `--incremental append` flag. You also need to create a Sqoop job, because that will capture the most recent `--last-value` and serialize it back to the saved job.

You should create a Sqoop job which looks something like this.

```
sqoop job \
--create jobName \
-- \
import \
jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port:sid \
--username user \
--password fileOnHDFS.password \
--table tableName \
--incremental lastmodified \
--check-column UPDATE_DATUM \
--last-value 1985.01.01 \
--merge-key ID \
```

More details can be found in the [Sqoop User Guide (v1.4.6)](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html)